# How can I realistically simulate audio for multi-sensor processing?

Tags: unreal-4, audio, simulations

I am performing audio simulations in Unreal Engine 4.

Ideally, I need realistic audio propagations. So microphones at multiple locations will experience propagation delays related to their distance from a sound source. Basically to be able to do spatial signal processing with a microphone array.

I have done some experiments with the Steam Audio plugin but I don't think that the propagation delays are built-in. Some research points to needing to add the propagation delays in post processing, but if the sound source is moving, then the problem becomes difficult.

How can I implement this in my project?

Comment: I've no idea how to do any of this in Unreal specifically, but I think it might help to be clear what you mean by "realistic". What realistic features are critical for your application? Do you need the audio equivalent of "ray tracing" using spatial convolution (which could go down a rabbit hole of complexity) or would it be sufficient to put a single delay on the signal and reduce its power proportional to the distance to each mic, etc.? Maybe single delays could possibly be modeled as a future audio event that you put on the queue to take place at the mic locations.